# What do I put in the save() method when trying to store an image in a database on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save an image into the database using Laravel. At the moment I am getting an error message:"Method App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::save does not exist." The desired output is to be able to store the image into the database in laravel along with my other product variables. I have included code of some parts I think is relevant to this question. I also don't have a save() method, it says it can't find a save() method.

ProductController@store

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'productImage' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('productImage')) {
        $image = $request->file('productImage');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $this->save();
    }
    $data = request()->validate([
        'productName'            =>  'required',
        'productLink'      =>  'required',
        'productPrice'      =>  'required',
        'productDescription'      =>  'required'
    ]);
    $product = new Product([
        'productName'            =>    $request->get('productName'),
        'productLink'      =>    $request->get('productLink'),
        'productPrice'      =>  $request->get('productPrice'),
        'productDescription'      =>  $request->get('productDescription')
    ]);
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/pr');
}
```

createProduct.blade.php

```
<form action="/storeProduct" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
@csrf
  <label for="productName">Product Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productName') }}"><br>
  @error('productName') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productImage">Product Image:</label><br>
  <input type="file" id="productImage" name="productImage" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productImage') }}"><br>
  @error('productImage') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productLink">Product Link:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productLink" name="productLink" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productLink') }}"><br>
  @error('productLink') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productPrice">Product Price:</label><br>
  <input type="decimal" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" autocomplete="off" value="{{ 
old('productPrice') }}"><br>
  @error('productPrice') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="productDescription">Product Description:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="productDescription" name="productDescription" autocomplete="off" value=" 
   {{ old('productDescription') }}"><br>
  @error('productDescription') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/storeProduct', 'ProductController@store');
```

I still don't understand what is wrong with my code, and why it isn't storing the image, I was following what someone else has done on another stackoverflow question. I have my GitHub repository below if you want to see my full code.

https://github.com/xiaoheixi/blog

Comment: have the Product class inherited ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model```? have you added ```Product``` into namespace with ```use App\Product```?

Comment: Check my solution below it is now fixed. The solution from me below shows what is missing from the problem above.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `$this->save()` calls a method named `save` of the `ProductController`. You don't have such a method in the controller and even if you have one, it's not a good practice and likely to be cause of error if you call controller's another method from the method of the same controller.

Consider below code;

```php
// Get image file from response
$image_file = $request->file('productImage');

// Save uploaded image to `local` disk and get path
$image_path = $image_file->storeAs('images', time().'.'.$image_file->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'local');

// Create product record
Product::create([
    'productName' => $request->get('productName'),
    'productLink' => $request->get('productLink'),
    'productPrice' => $request->get('productPrice'),
    'productDescription' => $request->get('productDescription'),
    'productImage' => $image_path,
]);

// No need to call `save()` function
```

Hope this helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much, you allowed me to grasp the understanding so I can actually put two pieces of code together and made it work.

Answer (score 1):

the error is due to this line :

> $this->save();

It's trying to call a function save() who don't exist on your controller

Comment: That is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to come to a fix for this question. Its my own question, and I am now uploading my own solution that fixes this problem. Big shoutout to ElektaKode for providing me the essential knowledge to perform this operation.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'productName'            =>  'required',
        'productImage' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'productLink'      =>  'required',
        'productPrice'      =>  'required',
        'productDescription'      =>  'required'
    ]);
    $image_file = $request->file('productImage');
    $image_path = $image_file->storeAs('images', time().'.'.$image_file->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'local');
    $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
    $name = time().'.'.$image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image_file->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $product = new Product([
        'productName'            =>    $request->get('productName'),
        'productImage' => $image_path,
        'productLink'      =>    $request->get('productLink'),
        'productPrice'      =>  $request->get('productPrice'),
        'productDescription'      =>  $request->get('productDescription')
    ]);
    
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/pr');
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help and I hope I can help future Professional Experience students from Western Sydney University if they come across a client who requires an ecommerce website as well.

Answer (score 0):

this error is accourding this code line `$this->save()` just delete it .
you also have another problem reacording a new product, you can just modify your method :

```php
Product::create([
    'productName'            =>  $request->get('productName'),
    'productLink'            =>  $request->get('productLink'),
    'productPrice'           =>  $request->get('productPrice'),
    'productDescription'     =>  $request->get('productDescription'),
    'image'                  =>  $name
]);
//there's no need to call save method
return redirect('/pr');
```

while using eloquent you don't have to call save method

> be sure that you add all this column in your model fillable

Comment: Thanks for helping me, my solution to this problem has been shown in an answer above.